# Do Python Implementation use Cache Oblivious Data Structures?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

I was reading an [article](https://rcoh.me/posts/cache-oblivious-datastructures/) on the benefits of cache oblivious data structures and found myself wondering if the Python implementations (CPython) use this approach? If not, is there a technical limitation preventing it?

Answer (score 2):

I would say this is mostly irrelevant for built-in (standard library) Python data structures.

- Creating a new data type in Python means creating a class, which is not a bare-bones wrapper of underlying primitive types or method pointers, but rather is a particular type of struct that has lots of additional metadata coming from Python object data model.
- There is no native tree data structure in Python. There are lists, arrays, and array-based hash tables (dict, set), along with some extensions to these like in the `collections` module. Third party tree / trie / etc., implementations are free to offer a cache-oblivious implementation if it suits the intended usage. This would include CPython C-level implementations such as with custom extensions modules or via a tool like Cython.
- NumPy `ndarray` is a contiguous array data structure for which the user may choose the data type (i.e. the user could, in theory, choose a weird data type that is not easily made into a multiple of the machine architecture's cache size). Perhaps some customization could be improved there, for fixed data type (and maybe the same is true for `array.array`), but I am wondering how many array / linear algebra algorithms benefit from some sort of customized cache obliviousness -- normally these sorts of libraries are written to assume use of a particular data type, like int32 or float64, specifically based on the cache size, and employ dynamic memory reallocation, like doubling, to amortize cost of certain operations. For example, your linked article mentions that finding the max over an array is "intrinsically" cache oblivious ... because it's contiguous, you make the maximum possible use of each cache line you read, and you only read the minimal number of cache lines. Perhaps for treating an array like a heap or something, you could be clever about rearranging the memory layout to be optimal regardless of cache size, but it wouldn't be the role of a general purpose array to have its implementation customized like that based on a very specialized use case (an array having the heap property).

In short, I would turn the question around on you and say, given the data structures that are standard in Python, do you see particular trade-offs between dynamic resizing, dynamic typing and (perhaps most importantly) general random access pattern assumptions vs. having a cache oblivious implementation backing them?